# Why program stops iterating before execution is complete in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I don't know why my program stops iterating at 4298 iteration. The program does what it is suppose to do when the list contains 100 items or something like that.

`this->getList()` contains 5000 items. I am stress testing my program

This is the function that causes the problem:

```
map<Coordinate, map<Coordinate, double>> NearestPoints::allDistances() {

map<Coordinate, map<Coordinate, double>> result = map<Coordinate, map<Coordinate, double>>();

int count = 0;

list<Coordinate> list1 = this->getList();

for (list<Coordinate>::iterator iterator1 = list1.begin(), end = list1.end(); iterator1 != end; iterator1++)
{

    cout << ++count << endl;

    Coordinate coordinate1 = *iterator1;

    result.insert(make_pair(coordinate1,map<Coordinate,double>()));

    list<Coordinate> list2 = this->getList();

    list2.remove(coordinate1);

    for (list<Coordinate>::iterator iterator2 = list2.begin(), internalEnd = list2.end(); iterator2 != internalEnd; iterator2++)
    {
        Coordinate coordinate2 = *iterator2;

        /*
        if (result.find(coordinate2) != result.end())
        {
            result.at(coordinate1).insert(make_pair(coordinate2, result.at(coordinate2).at(coordinate1)));

        }
        */

        //else
        //{
            result.at(coordinate1).insert(make_pair(coordinate2, this->distanceBetweenTwoPoints(coordinate1.getX(),coordinate1.getY(),coordinate2.getX(),coordinate2.getY())));
        //}
    }
}
return result;
```

}

Comment: what does stop-iterating mean??it crashed,hung ??

Comment: No it didn't crashed . After the 4298 iteration it just prints "Press any key to continue" even though the main hasn't even executed fully. When the list consists of 100 coordinates i works fine.

Comment: what is the size of `Coordinate`?

Comment: 24 bytes is the size of Coordinate

Comment: list<Coordinate> NearestPoints::getList() {

 return this->Coordinates;
}

Comment: @AhsanMirza Why do you return a copy of the list? And why does your code that calls `getList` make a copy of that? It just seems like no effort has been put into making this code sensible. The way you construct `list2` is bizarre. You make a copy of a copy of `Coordinates`, when you already have one, just to remove one entry from it, when you could just skip that entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running out of memory.  You have 5000 entries in the list.  You have a map to a map of those entries, for 5000 * 5000 map entries, or 25M.  Each map entry consists of the 24 bytes for the key (Coordinate), 8 bytes for the value (double), plus several pointers for the left, right, and parent nodes in the map.  That's at least 44 bytes for each node, with each of the 25M nodes having additional overhead for the memory allocation.

Comment: You are right . Is there anyway I can expand the memory ? I am running it on Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Compile it as a 64 bit process, if you're on a 64 bit windows.  Otherwise you'll have to rethink how you keep track of your data.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
Coordinate coordinate1 = *iterator1;
```

You are copying what the iterator is pointing to

You probably meant

```
Coordinate& coordinate1 = *iterator1;
```

sames goes for your inner loop. You end up with a lot of copies.

Comment: I tried it but didn't worked . Thanks for the help regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue.Ran my code in release mode and it worked perfectly